# Mismatch in Spark Shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to count some data from a specific field in the Spark Shell using this:

```
dfEquipmenttorecover.where($"key_number"==="12884612884").count
```

But I get this error

```
<console>:51: error: type mismatch;
 found   : StringContext
 required: ?{def $: ?}
Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:
 both method StringToColumn in class SQLImplicits of type (sc: StringContext)spark.implicits.StringToColumn
 and method StringToAttributeConversionHelper in trait ExpressionConversions of type (sc: StringContext)org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl.expressions.StringToAttributeConversionHelper
 are possible conversion functions from StringContext to ?{def $: ?}
       dfEquipmenttorecover.where($"key_number"==="12884612884").count
```

I'm using Scala version 2.11.12 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_201)
and Spark version 2.4.7.7.1.7.0-551 and imported `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl.expressions.StringToAttributeConversionHelper` and `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl.expressions._`

I have more libraries imported, but I don't know if this bug comes from that.

Answer (score 0):

You need use *org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit* for your string value. Becose === compare columns, and on the right you need column created by literal "12884612884".

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
dfEquipmenttorecover.where($"key_number"===lit("12884612884")).count
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion Alex, but am getting the same error.. and I even imported the  library funcions.lit.

Comment: try explicit use col instead $

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
dfEquipmenttorecover.where(col("key_number")===lit("12884612884")).count

Comment: yea, i can use col instead of $, but before i used to apply ... i moved from putty to mobaxterm ... i havent tried to do it with putty again...but i dont know if has something to do about this ....